# How to "refresh" a deployed application in Wildfly?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, application-server

I´m quite new to Java EE and have a comprehension question about running an application in the application server, in my case Wildfly 10.

My Problem is, that objects apparently keep their state, once they where instantiated on application start up, even if i close and re-open the browser session. In my case, i´m using a bean that tries to open a jdbc connection and writes to the facelet´s messages in case something goes wrong.

So, to test the scenario i shut down the database and started the application. As expected, the error message comes up. Now, after restarting the database, it is still not connecting and giving me the "no database" message. A complete restart of the application server is necessary in order to have the bean start over new.

So the question is, what do i have to do, to re-initialize all involved object instances of my application?

Here is the code of the bean in question:

```
@Named
@Stateless
public class CoworkerProducer 
{
    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    @Resource(lookup="java:/JMPostgres")
    private DataSource dsJM;

    public void addCoworkers(Long projectId) 
    {
        Project managedProject = em.find(Project.class, projectId);
        Long jmId = managedProject.getJmId();
        try {
            Connection con = dsJM.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM employees e, departments d WHERE e.department_id = d.id AND d.project_id = " + jmId);
            ResultSet result =  ps.executeQuery();  
            while(result.next()){
                Coworker cow = new Coworker();
                cow.setProject(managedProject);
                em.persist(cow);
            }       
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            final FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "no database!", null));
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you injecting `EntityManager` and injecting `DatasSource` at the same time?

Comment: because i read some data from the DataSource (external RDBMS) and store that data in objects that get persisted by the entity manager then

Answer (score 0):

It's best practice to let the container, in your case Wildfly 10, handle the database connection, You can configure that in the standalone.xml file.

[Documentation for configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/DataSource+configuration?_sscc=t)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, create a (pooled) Datasource in Wildfly and enable connection validation and connection retries in Wildfly. That way, Wildfly will manage your database connection and reestablish connection if it failed.

Once you installed the MySQL driver in Wildfly, you can create the datasource on the Wildfly admin console (by default it runs on port `9990`) or with the JBoss CLI.

Further reading:

- [Datasource configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/DataSource+configuration)

Comment: Actually I already did it that way. I´ve created the Postgres Datasource in Wildfly, although i left all the pooling and timeout settings to default values. Is it a question of specifications? If so, how do i have to set parameters to have Wildfly try to re-open the connection for each new browser session?

Comment: Configuration of the Datasource will depend on your application usage of the DB resource (e.g., DB connection). There is no specific, default configuration values for the connection pooling in any of the Java EE specifications.

Comment: Thanks Buhake. I just want Wildfly to try to re-connect to the Db for each new session, or better for each new request of the JSF page.